# Database access with Angular

Tags: mysql, angular

Is it possible to access MySQL databases in Angular framework or would that be insecure like other Javascript and I will need to post to a PHP page to retrieve `data/json` from a database

Comment: use firebase https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Yes it's Possible.

Comment: You can't access MySQL from Angular directly. You need a server that provides a REST API (or WebSocket, ...) that processes requests from Angular, forwards them to the database and returns the result to the Angular application. The suggested Firebase provides such an API as do many others for all kinds of databases.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt recommend FireBird because it quickly builds up limitations, plus there are alot of drawbacks you cant really see, a good article that goes into detail about this is; [Crisp.chat - Why you should never use firebird](https://crisp.chat/blog/why-you-should-never-use-firebase-realtime-database/) I would personally recommend using backend PHP to post and pull with to ensure database security and more backend complex logic you might need, Use MySQL for general use like blogs, users, etc but id personally suggest MongoDB for chat features but that is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Angular is a client side rendering framework that why angular not support database connectivity.you have to use a rest api.use express js for developing a rest api. express js and angular uses a same language that why it is easy for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
// Application module
var dbApp = angular.module('dbApp',[]);
dbApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

// Function to get data from the database
getDatafromDatabase();
function getDatafromDatabase(){
// Sending request to php files
$http.post('databaseFiles/yourfile.php').success(function(data){
// Stored the returned data into scope
$scope.dbData = data;
});
}
```

And php file which we want to call in angularjs script (yourfile.php)

```
 <?php
// Including database connections
require_once 'database_connections.php';
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database
$query = "SELECT * from [table_name] ORDER BY [table_column]";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}
}
// Return json array containing data from the databasecon
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

HTML file look like this

```
 <html ng-app="dbApp">
...
<body>
<div  ng-controller="DbController">
...
<!-- Table to show date from database -->
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
<th>Column4</th>
<th>Column5</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="dbData in dbData">
<td>
<span>{{dbData .Column1}}</span></td>
<td>{{dbData .Column2}}</td>
<td>{{dbData .Column3}}</td>
<td>{{dbData .Column4}}</td>
<td>{{dbData .Column5}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Code seems usable by looking and not testing but I believe the original post was about Angular 2+ not the original AngularJS D: