# Can we access a Database via Angular only?

Tags: angular, database

I have my WEB teacher keep telling me about creating web apps fully client sided, which means that the access to the database is done on the client side without backend.
He claims that this will be the futre trend of creating web apps .
I just wanted to know if it's possible to access  a database with angular only without using any kind of backend ( Express , php ...) and how.
I know this would generate massive security fails in my app , but I just want to try and find those fails by myself thanks.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "database", but you should do some research into [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Comment: Please see this answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644574/database-access-with-angular

Comment: I hope you aren't paying too much for that teacher. It's nigh impossible to fully secure the database if you are allowing the front end to make direct changes to it. SQL injections much?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you consider [Prisma](http://prisma.io) with graphQL you can manage all your queries with frontend-only

Comment: Prisma is the backend in that case.

Comment: You right but it's mostly configuration and less backend programming

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. If your backend can access db so does the front end.
The biggest issue as I see it is security. Since there is no backend the db credentials must be stored in the client's machine. You should account for the possibility that the end user knows your db username and password. In rare cases it is acceptable for example the UI needs only read access to publicly available information but such situation is rare.